# JQuery SmoothDivScroll works awkwardly

Tags: jquery, scroll, colorbox, smooth-scrolling

I've been working with SmoothDivScroll on one of my site but it doesn't seem to work properly. I've got a scrollable gallery with colorbox. You can check the site here:

http://www.lazza.com.mx/ee/obras

I've tested it with Chrome, Firefox, and IE and all of them have the same problem: sometimes it loads and sometimes it doesn't. And when it does load, when you guide the scrolling with the cursor it stops suddenly instead of scrolling smoothly constantly.

Any help will be very welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by your CSS. You have a rule that looks like this:

```
div.scrollableArea img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

But since you have wrapped the images inside the scrollable area in a-tags you should target the a-tags instead, like this:

```
div.scrollableArea a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should solve your problem. If you are unsure, take a look at the [Colorbox example](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/colorbox.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Great work with your SmoothDivScroll by the way! Unfortunately it didn't work. And I've checked the colorbox example before asking here, and compared it with my code but didn't find anything. Once again thanks for the answer, if you can keep helping me I would really appreciate it because I'm really clueless.

Comment: I've copied your Colorbox example page and implemented the autoScrollingMode: "onstart" on it and it happens the same thing that it happens on my page. Whenever I scroll using my mouse, it only scrolls for some images and then suddenly stops =S. That's one of my problems. The other one is that, like I said, it just doesn't work at all. That doesn't happen with your example, so that's gotta be something in my code. Hope you can help me out Thomas. I will update you on anything I find.

Comment: You can take a look at my attempt to make your example in autoScrollingMode: http://www.lazza.com.mx/colorboxexample.html

Comment: I looked at the page you sent but it works for me? Could the error be caused by something else?

Comment: Sorry for not replying in so many days. I was out of the city and without an internet connection. What works for you? my colorbox example with the autoScrollingMode? If that's what your talking about, scroll using the cursor, you will see that it stops suddenly. Cheers

Comment: Yes, I looked at the example that you posted (lazza.com.mx/colorboxexample.html) and it worked like it should. If you want endless scrolling while scrolling with the mouse you should look at the option manualContinuousScrolling. Otherwise it will stop scrolling when it reaches the first/last image.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works perfectly. Now the problem just remains in my website (http://www.lazza.com.mx/ee/obras). I think is some kind of problem with the autoScrolling option. What do you think. It may be a problem with that option or is just my website? thanks in advance.

Comment: Problem solved Thomas. Thanks for everything. I just copied the code from your example. The bad thing is that I didn't get to understand what was exactly what was making the web crash. Thanks anyway